# Call the inner method in outer class through inner class reference

Tags: java, class

I want to call the Inner class method in outer class, but it isn't working. I also made a reference of Inner class object and try to call the method, but also invalid again

```
class Outer{

    int a;

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Show Method");
    }

    Inner obj=new Inner();

    obj.display();

     class Inner{

        public void display() {
            System.out.println("Display Method");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `obj.display();` is in the wrong place. You can't have that statement in the body of the class. Put it inn a method. Seems you need a main method.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Finally please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Comment: "But isn't working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Otherwise you'll get fried ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what you are trying to do, however, the *syntactically smallest possible change* you can make to get your code to compile (any maybe do what you want, although it is not clear to me *what* it is that you are trying to achieve), would be to move the method call into an [*instance initializer*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6):

```java
class Outer {
    int a;

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Show Method");
    }

    Inner obj = new Inner();

    { obj.display(); }
//  ↑                ↑

    class Inner {
        public void display() {
            System.out.println("Display Method");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, given a suitable [program entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4):

```java
class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Outer();
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
Display Method
```